# My Laravel Routes Are Not Working Error 404

Tags: laravel

I am working on an existing laravel project. Problem is whenever I create a new route the new route does not function. Also I am not receiving this error

> GET http://localhost/khawaja%20sons/khawjapos.unialsolutions.com/public/products/warehouse 404 (Not Found).

[Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EedSU.png)

[ProductController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9guR.png)

[link from where I am using the route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyjod.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXKSu.png)

Comment: please post actual code and use code formatter, do not post images

Comment: Which version of Laravel?

Comment: laravel version 6

Answer (score 0):

You have a two option how to use routes after you are set them:
first one :

`<a href="{{url('product/warehouse')}}">Link</a>`

You have tried this method but, you need to remove `asset` function, because asset function return path to public folder

The second way to use route and the way I recommend is to use `route names`

`<a href="{{route('products.product_warehouse')}}">Link</a>`

I recommend this way, because if you change the path in future, your change will be applied to everywhere you use route name, you don't need to be worry is route will work

Comment: I have tried both options before. Both are giving the same error.

Comment: `http://localhost/products/warehouse ` Your route should look like this. can u try to open manually and see is it working

Comment: i think the problem is not in the way how i am using the route because the route is not present in the route list.

Comment: php artisan route:list

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both options before. Both are giving the same error